# How do I remove unused dependencies with govendor

Tags: go, govendor

I want to cleanup my vendor folder in my golang project. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

After good amount of  looking around, I found that there is an easy one-line command to do this:

`govendor remove +unused`

Comment: At first, you need to install it by the `go get -u github.com/kardianos/govendor` command.

Answer (score 0):

What about using this commands?

```
go mod tidy --> removes dependencies from go.mod 
go mod vendor --> removes libraries from vendor
```

This will remove all unused libraries